# Rspec.config before(:each) except for specific :types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to get a `before(:each)` block to run for all specs *except*  `type: :feature`.

The only way I can get it working is to cut-and-paste and have separate config blocks for each type. (`:type => :model`, `:type => :service`, etc.)

**spec/rails_helper.rb**

```
# To speed up tests, stub all Paperclip saving and reading to/from S3
config.before(:each, :type => :model) do
  allow_any_instance_of(Paperclip::Attachment).to receive(:save).and_return(true)
end
```

Is there a more DRY approach?

Comment: have you tried `config.before(:each, :type =>  lambda {|v| v != :feature})`

Comment: @Yule it works! and I really like this approach. Post an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Great! Just a hunch from some other docs I read. Answer added. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you're passing into your before block, is a '[conditions hash](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/5375dcdfdb5460a51d5003de76eb124997fa26ea/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb#L67)'. RSpec will only apply the before to those examples or contexts that match those conditions.

The hash is fairly flexible and you can do straight forward things such as `type: :model` as you've done, but you can query any type of metadata, with arbitrary names.

As an example from [filter run excluding](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/5375dcdfdb5460a51d5003de76eb124997fa26ea/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb#L1058)

```
  :foo => 'bar'
  :foo => /^ba/
  :foo => lambda {|v| v == 'bar'}
  :foo => lambda {|v,m| m[:foo] == 'bar'}
```

`:foo` could be anything for example, type. But it gives you a load of flexibility, especially with the lambda syntax to be able to very specific under what circumstances you want to run your specs.

In your case you could do something like this:

```
config.before(:each, :type => lambda {|v| v != :feature}) do
  allow_any_instance_of(Paperclip::Attachment).to receive(:save).and_return(true)
end
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use `unless` to judge example metadata via an `around` hook.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.around(:each) do |example|
    example.run unless example.metadata[:type].eql? :feature
  end
end
```

Comment: This approach did not work for me. It raised the following error: `RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::WrongScopeError metadata is not available from within an example (e.g. an it block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. before, let, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a describe or context block).` However, I was able to achieve something similar by following this advice:
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/2728#issuecomment-1300559036