# before(:all) except one - is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I use `before(:all)` in my tests for database initialization, which causes no problems for my test cases... except one. I'd like to run this special case before or after others, as I want to initialize database for it separately. Is there some way to do this? I'd like to avoid replacing `before(:all)` with `before(:each)`, because I'd like to keep my tests fast. Is it possible?

Comment: You should check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417737/beforeeach-for-all-tests-except-one

Comment: I've checked out it. As I wrote, I'd like to avoid using `before(:each)`, what works differently. In my case it's necessary to avoid mixing execution of my special case with my common cases, because its initialization will affect common cases.

Comment: How about taking that specific test case out of the `before(:all)` block?

Comment: @chumakoff - hm, can I do this when my `before(:all)` block concerns many separate methods?

Comment: Look at this post.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655446/rspec-config-beforeeach-except-for-specific-types  .  Maybe try an exception in a config block?     config.before(:all, ....

Answer (score 0):

> before(:all) except one - is it possible?

Probally not. `before(:all)` runs before all the examples in that scope and there is no way to hoist examples above it.

I think a better idea is to work around the problem and just create different contexts:

```
RSpec.describe Thing do
  context "with :all" do
    before(:all) do
      # ...
    end
    # ...
  end
  context "without :all" do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Use [shared contexts](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context) or the outer scope if you need to share setup steps or variables. Use [shared examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/example-groups/shared-examples) if you want to run the same examples in different contexts.

> I'd like to run this special case before or after others, as I want to
>   initialize database for it separately. Is there some way to do this?

You can use the [`--order defined`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/order) option when running rspec to run the tests sequentially. However this sets you up for test ordering issues than can mask critical bugs in the application. Fast test are worthless if they don't catch bugs.

You can also use [`:order => :defined` metadata](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/configuration/overriding-global-ordering) to set the order per context. And for the reason in the beginning of this question this is a fools errand.